# How to select second element with JQUERY when clicked on image?

Tags: jquery

The code below working for only first div. I can't display other divs when i clicked on the other "img"s.
Do you know a method to reach second (next) element?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.imgOpenClose').click(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("src") == "images/openTree.gif") {
                $(this).attr("src", "images/closeTree.gif");
                $(this).parent().find('div').eq(0).show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).attr("src", "images/openTree.gif");
                $(this).parent().find('div').eq(0).hide();
            }
        });
});
```

[image: Wanna open table when i clicked on plus images]

[image: And wanna see the table inside this div]

Comment: Can you give us some example HTML for the page you want your javascript to run on?  Otherwise, your question lacks detail, and we can't really help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a break element following the image, you'll need to use nextAll and select the first DIV instead of simply using `next` with a filter as in my original answer.

```
$('.imgOpenClose').click( function() {
    $(this).nextAll('div:first').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be $(this).next('div') instead?

Comment: @markusk -- good catch, I thought the DIVs were all at the same level.

Comment: alert($(this).next('div').html()); => returns null

Answer (score 1):

If you have several images with the same class-tag, you can still do it without having to append a unique id:

```
$(function() {
    $('.imgOpenClose').click(function() {
        $(this).next('div').children('table').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: As you see div before table has display property as none. Thats why, i should toggle div tag. 
But 
    alert( $(this).next('div').html() );

returns null. Why jquery couldn't find next div ?

Comment: next is next sibling only. If it is not a div then it will be null. the filter for next is so you can say give me the next sibling but only if it is a div.